# Use $_GET to echo input value attribute

Tags: javascript, php, html, get

I have this html/javascript script. Every time the user clicks on the map it opens a form. At the same time, it send the coordinates to an input tag.

**htmlFile.html**

```
    <div id="sidebar" class="sidebar">
        <form action="data.php" method="get">
            <input id="lat" type="hidden" value="">
            <input id="long" type="hidden" value="">
            <input id="name" type="text" name="name">
            <input id="surname" type="text" name="surname">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
     </div>

     map.on('click', addMarker);
            function addMarker(e){
                // Add marker to map at click location; add popup window
                var newMarker = new L.marker(e.latlng).addTo(map);
                sidebar.show();
                document.getElementById("lat").value = e.latlng.lat;
                document.getElementById("long").value = e.latlng.lng;
                console.log(e.latlng.lat);
                console.log(e.latlng.lng);
            }
```

I would like to be able to echo the "lat" and "long" value.

This is my PHP script:
**data.php**

```
$name = $_GET['name'];
$surname = $_GET['surname'];
echo $surname;
$lat = $_GET["lat"]; # This is were I have a problem
echo $lat;
```

Comment: Replace `$_GET` with `$_REQUEST`. I _think_ that will work

Comment: To be sent to the PHP from the browser all inputs must contain a valid `name="something"` attribute, so `<input id="lat" name="lat" type="hidden" value="">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add name attribute to this piece of code `<input id="lat" type="hidden" value=""> :)`